# Создание транзакции FireBase с помощью Xamarin

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-database, firebase-android

Необходимо просто поле count постоянно добавлять +1, как я понимаю если я сделаю так:

```cs
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://patriot-5acda.firebaseio.com/"))
    {            
        string countStr = await firebase.Child("Patriot").Child("Server").Child("Count").OnceSingleAsync<string>();
        int count = int.Parse(countStr);
        count++;
        await firebase.Child("Patriot").Child("Server").Child("Count").PutAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(count.ToString()));
    }        
}
```

то если 2 человека одновременно это сделают пройдет лишь +1, а не +2, по моей логике необходима транзакция, может кто подскажет как ее написать?

Comment: `convert.ToInt32(count)+=1;` вот эта строчка точно компилируется? Быть может должно быть что-то типа `int c = int.Parse(count) + 1`? Что такое `Count`? Перепроверьте код в вопросе, он не связанный, и он не скомпилируется, много синтаксических ошибок, исправьте его в вопросе.

Comment: Перепроверил код, вот 100% рабочий, подскажите как сделать транзакцию, а то моя тупая голова не может понять исходя из источников

Comment: Да, после того как вы отредактировали крд, он стал рабочим. Но все равно был написан весьма странно. Я немного причесал, если вы не против, так будет удобнее его читать отвечающему. Ответа про транзакцию я не знаю, так как с FB не работал.